# Attributes with PopupFeature: how to show all

Tags: openlayers, popup, ol-ext

I'm using the '[Popup Feature](https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/popup/map.popup.feature.html)' popup example to show the information of my layers, with Openlayers.

I'm showing two attributes in the popup: ID and NAME. But, I have several other attributes.
How do I show them all, without having to write each of the attributes? I won't change their title.

The popup code is as follows:

```
var popup = new ol.Overlay.PopupFeature({
    popupClass: 'default anim',
    select: select_interaction,
    canFix: true,
    template: {
        title: 
             'NAME',   // only display the name
            
        attributes: 
        {
            'NAME': { title: 'NAME' },
            'ID': { title: 'ID' },
             
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in the [docs](https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/doc/doc-pages/ol.Overlay.PopupFeature.html) for `template` you can also provide a function that takes a `feature` as argument.

Your code could then look like this:

```js
var popup = new ol.Overlay.PopupFeature({
    popupClass: 'default anim',
    select: select_interaction,
    canFix: true,
    template: function (feature) {
        var properties = feature.getProperties();
        var attributes = {};
        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(properties)) {
            // add your your business logic here ... 
            // ... maybe rename or hide some properties ... 
            attributes[key] = {
                title: value
            };
        }
        return {
            title: 'NAME',
            attributes: attributes
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks, that was exactly what I needed. I managed to adapt to what I need to show.